# How can I convert string in JTextField to hexadecimal from reading a csv file without the use of any existing function?

Tags: java, file, csv, try-catch

I am pretty new Java, so a little help will be appreciated.

## Things to consider before attempting the problem

So I have a JTextField and a button. When the user types a message in the JTextField and presses the button, what the button must do is call a csv table which has all the lists of all the hexadecimal and convert each string character within the JTextField to a hexadecimal value, and return it.

1. My button name is called **send**
2. My JTextField is called **text**
3. My **fileNameDefined** is the path to my csv table
4. My **cols[2]** is the third column in my csv table that has the values of hexadecimal
5. I am deliberately not planning to use StringtoHex or any existing function.

This is my code the I have produced

```js
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String fileNameDefined = "C:/Users/Naseebullah/SecondMinorCourseWork/src/naseebullahnazrin/ascii_table.csv";
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
              reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNameDefined));
              String eachLine = reader.readLine();
              char[] s = text.getText().toCharArray();

              while ((eachLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] cols = eachLine.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {

                  if (text.getText().contains(cols[2])) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                  }

                }

              }

            } catch (IOException t) {
              t.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
```

csv file:

[image: CSV file]

## Problem

My Problem here is that I can't make my program compare my string to the hexadecimal in the csv table and return.

A little help will be highly appreciated.

Kindest regards

Comment: @Berger Its not because they are using builtin function. I don't want that. My approach is way different.

Comment: Could you edit your post by providing a sample of what your file contains ?

Comment: @Berger Hi please check it now. Thank you